# How can I determine the type (e.g. many-to-one) of a dynamic SQLAlchemy relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have the following SQLAlchemy classes defined:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    computers = relationship('Computer', backref=backref('owner', lazy='dynamic'))

class Computer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'computer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ownerid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))
```

Suppose further that I have accessed the lazy query object this way:

```
relation = getattr(Computer, 'owner')
```

How can I determine if `relation` refers to a single instance of `Person` (that is, in a many-to-one relationship, like in this example), or if `relation` refers to a collection of instances (like in a one-to-many relationship)? In other words, how can I determine the relationship type of a dynamic SQLAlchemy relationship object?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question right, but with in your example, why don't you just check whether it is a collection (e.g. a list) or a single item? This is completely independent from SQLAlchemy and would make use of SQLAlchemy's ORM feature and abstract from the database completely.

Comment: You are mostly right: I think the correct solution is to check whether `isinstance(relation, list)`---if true then we can just use it like a list, but if false you have to call `relation.one()` in order to map the relation to a concrete instance. If you add an answer below, I can reward you (please incorporate the caveat I've stated here, if you can).

Answer (score 3):

If we suppose `model = Computer` and `relation = 'owner'` as in the question, then the following attribute is `True` if and only if the relation is a list of instances as opposed to a single instance:

```
model._sa_class_manager[relation].property.uselist
```

You can then use this to test whether or not to call the `one()` method on the result of `getattr(model, relation)`:

```
if model._sa_class_manager[relation].property.uselist:
    related_instances = getattr(model, relation)
else:
    related_instance = getattr(model, relation).one()
```

I am not confident, however, that this is the best solution.